# How to automate patch(some SVN commits) in IIS Hosting?

Tags: iis, hosting, patch

I have IIS Server where code is hosted. After committing some code I want to host only that changes(patch). I don't want to host complete code or to change dll manually. How can I automate this patch hosting?

Comment: There is no such thing from Microsoft. Either you develop your own, or see if the search engines can lead you to some third party tools.

Comment: We use [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) and [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/) to do this.

Comment: @LexLi How can I develop my own? Please suggest me.

Comment: @GabrielLuci TeamCity deploy complete code everytime. So I don't think it will solve my problem.